# How do I enable greedy MigrationHeuristic in Karmic?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, xorg, xorg.conf

My laptop performs very poorly for 2d graphics. For example, Docky's zoom effect and compiz effects are very choppy. In Jaunty, I was able to fix this by adding the following line under the "Device" section in my xorg.conf:

```
Option "MigrationHeuristic" "greedy"
```

In Karmic, there is no xorg.conf by default, so I copied my old one (from Jaunty). However, everything is still slow. Here is my xorg.conf:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
    Option  "MigrationHeuristic" "greedy"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
    Device      "Configured Video Device"
EndSection
```

From googling about, it sounds like "MigrationHeuristic" is only an option for the "EXA" mode, while Karmic has switched the intel driver to "UXA". So I tried adding this line under the "Device" section:

```
Option "AccelMethod" "exa"
```

But this didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in Ubuntu Karmic, because of the switch from "EXA" mode to "UXA" mode. The problem with Docky specifically, however, can be fixed by launching it as `docky --netbook` or `docky -n` (you must be running [Docky2](https://launchpad.net/~docky-core/+archive/ppa), not Docky1 (the Docky in Gnome Do)). It is a bug in the Intel drivers (for some reason they perform very poorly rendering things with width or height between 1009 and 1024), and Docky2 provides a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given above is completely wrong. There is still a way to apply the Option    "MigrationHeuristic" "greedy". This is how you do it.

```
sudo service gdm stop
```

This stops Xserver and takes you to the Linux Prompt. Login with your credentials. From there do this.

```
sudo Xorg -configure
```

This creates a new file named xorg.conf.new in your home directory. After that type

```
sudo vim xorg.conf.new
```

Now add the Option `MigrationHeuristic "greedy"` line to your xorg.conf.new file under the "Device" section. Save and exit. Now type

```
startx
```

This starts up Xserver again. This time everything should appear snappy.